# Неверно работает автоподстановка в Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, email, autocomplete, password

В Google Chrome версии 63.0.3239.132 проявляется проблема с автоподстановкой адреса электронной почты в формах. В идеале хотелось бы отключить автоподстановку совсем, или хотя бы сделать так, чтобы подстановка происходила верно.
[image: Chrome autocomplete]

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    email: <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" /><br />
    tel: <input type="text" name="tel" autocomplete="off" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="hidden_email" style="display: none" />
    <input type="password" name="hidden_password" style="display: none" />
    password: <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Привожу минимальный пример кода. Поля email может и вовсе не быть. Но Chrome в любом случае думает, что ближайшее сверху поле к паролю является адресом электронной почты, хотя это может быть чем угодно другим, никнеймом, адресом, пин-кодом, Chrome в любом случае будет предлагать подставить туда email.

Раньше спасали скрытые (display: none) поля, но в последних версиях Chrome их просто игнорирует.

Кто знает как с этим бороться? В идеале отключить autocomplete совсем, или хотя бы сделать так, чтобы он верно подставлял.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас скопировал Ваш пример в сниппет и запустил. В поле e-mail предлагает подставить e-mail, в поле телефон - номер телефона. Т.е. все работает именно так как нужно. Версия `63.0.3239.132 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)`

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
    email: <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" /><br />
    tel: <input type="text" name="tel" autocomplete="off" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="hidden_email" style="display: none" />
    <input type="password" name="hidden_password" style="display: none" />
    password: <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Действительно, при наведении фокуса на поля email или телефон автоподстановка происходит верно. Однако у меня проблема с тем, что при подстановке пароля Chrome автоматически в паре с ним подставляет email, но уже не в то поле которое нужно. Т.е. проблема связана именно с автоподстановкой пароля и идущего в паре с ним emailа.